# Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports

Tags: ios, crash-reports, symbolicate

I'm looking to try and symbolicate my iPhone app's crash reports.

I retrieved the crash reports from iTunes Connect. I have the application binary that I submitted to the App Store and I have the dSYM file that was generated as part of the build.

I have all of these files together inside a single directory that is indexed by spotlight.

What now?

I have tried invoking:

```
symbolicatecrash crashreport.crash myApp.app.dSYM
```

and it just outputs the same text that is in the crash report to start with, not symbolicated.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can also see my answer at [iPhone SDK : Where is symbolicatecrash.sh located?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8648232/590956).  I list out where to find the `symbolicatecrash` command, how to use it, and how to find the dSYM file needed to do symbolication.

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash

Comment: I've created a script which may help: https://github.com/amleszk/scripts/blob/master/ios-crashlog-symbolicatecrash.sh

Comment: If anyone is wondering where can you get *.app, *.dSYM & crash logs to being with then look at my answer below.

Comment: Here's a very simple open source app for OS X that lets you simply drag a crash log and the corresponding .xcarchive (including dSYM) to symbolicate it: https://github.com/johnno1962/Symbolicate

Comment: You can refer this : https://medium.com/@Mrugraj/crash-re-symbolication-5c28d3a3a883

Answer (score 698, accepted):

Steps to analyze crash report from apple:

1. Copy the release .app file which was pushed to the appstore, the .dSYM file that was created at the time of release and the crash report receive from APPLE into a *FOLDER*.
2. OPEN terminal application and go to the folder created above (using `cd` command)
3. Run `atos -arch armv7 -o APPNAME.app/APPNAME MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH`. The memory location should be the one at which the app crashed as per the report.

Ex:  `atos -arch armv7  -o 'APPNAME.app'/'APPNAME' 0x0003b508`

This would show you the exact line, method name which resulted in crash.

Ex: `[classname functionName:]; -510`

**Symbolicating IPA**

if we use IPA for symbolicating - just rename the extention .ipa with .zip , extract it then we can get a Payload Folder which contain app. In this case we don't need .dSYM file.

**Note**

This can only work if the app binary does not have symbols stripped. By default release builds stripped the symbols. We can change it in project build settings "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to NO.

More details see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937300/453542)

Comment: Just a tip to @NaveenShan answer, a real-world example would do this  

`atos -o myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp 0x0000000100001f2c`  

and you get  
   
`-[HUDWindow sizedHUDBackground] (in myApp) + 1197`

Comment: Which address do you use, though?  The logs have two columns of addresses after each function, and the second has a + and an offset of some kind.  Like 0x332da010 0x332d9000 + 4112.

Comment: @OscarGoldman The second address eg:- In 0x332da010 0x332d9000 + 4112. use 0x332d9000.

Comment: Didn't work.  Maybe I don't have the right files to go with the crash report, idk.

Comment: @WolfLink Is you try to symbolicate the IPA or Adhoc?

Comment: Also, if used without an address, it allow you to analyse multiple locations by submitting them one by one.

Comment: This is the only solution for me with Xcode 4.4. I have tried everything else with no luck, nothing symbolicates any other way...

Comment: There are multiple issues with this answer: 1. This can only work if the app binary does not have symbols stripped. And release builds by default do have them stripped. 2. Even if the symbols are available, it will never ever show the line number. Only symbolicating with the dSYM will provide that. 3. You cannot simply use the memory address shown in the stack trace, the address has to be normalized against the start memory address the app is loaded into. More details see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028

Comment: @Oscar you must use the first number, the second one is the base adress + offset (in decimal). Infact f.e. I have this numbers com.myApp 0x000000010001dc66 0x100000000 + 121958 and if you translate 121958 in esadecimal it is 1dc66. Btw if you go more down the log to Binary Images section, in my case, there will be 0x100000000 -        0x100244ff7 +com.myApp that indicates the range of addresses that are part of my application.

Comment: I am not seeing expected result..atos -arch armv7 -o 'MobileApp.app'/'MobileApp' 0x68000
Result: 0x00068000 (in MobileApp) + 328... (lot of information here huh!!) I am using enterprise distributed ipa.

Comment: @Akki, Are you sure you are using the same IPA in which crash occurred?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same ipa. I extracted .app from it and copied in the folder with .crash and .dsym file.

Comment: @NaveenShan I have traced the UUID too. .app and .crash have same uuid.

Comment: Probably related to what Kerni said, but the approach described in this answer gives *completely* different results than `symbolicatecrash` when you cross-reference the two.  For instance, in `symbolicatecrash` I get 'InspectionViewController.m:2170', while using the same address with the technique in this answer gives 'AFHTTPClient.m:1220'.  Clearly one or the other is wrong.

Comment: I've written a tool for symbolication, which looks through all your xarchives trying to symbolicate a crashlog. https://github.com/soniccat/symb

Comment: If you need to manually do this (like from a screenshot of a crashlog), use the -l tag described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284459/548975 It does the math for you.

Comment: Damn, Apple has this much documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html when your simple answer solves 90% of the people that would have read Apple's page.

Comment: I hate Apple with a passion.

Answer (score 178):

After reading all these answers here in order to symbolicate a crash log (and finally succeeding) I think there are some points missing here that are really important in order to determine why the invocation of symbolicatecrash does not produce a symbolicated output.

There are 3 assets that have to fit together when symbolicating a crash log:

1. The crash log file itself (i.e. `example.crash`), either exported from XCode's organizer or received from iTunes Connect.
2. The `.app` package (i.e. `example.app`) that itself contains the app binary belonging to the crash log. If you have an `.ipa` package (i.e. `example.ipa`) then you can extract the `.app` package by unzipping the `.ipa` package (i.e. `unzip example.ipa`). Afterwards the `.app` package resides in the extracted `Payload/` folder.
3. The `.dSYM` package containing the debug symbols (i.e. `example.app.dSYM`)

Before starting symbolication you should check if all those artifacts match, which means that the crash log belongs to the binary you have and that the debug symbols are the ones produced during the build of that binary.

Each binary is referred by a UUID that can be seen in the crash log file:

```
...
Binary Images:
0xe1000 -    0x1f0fff +example armv7  <aa5e633efda8346cab92b01320043dc3> /var/mobile/Applications/9FB5D11F-42C0-42CA-A336-4B99FF97708F/example.app/example
0x2febf000 - 0x2fedffff  dyld armv7s  <4047d926f58e36b98da92ab7a93a8aaf> /usr/lib/dyld
...
```

In this extract the crash log belongs to an app binary image named example.app/example with UUID `aa5e633efda8346cab92b01320043dc3`.

You can check the UUID of the binary package you have with dwarfdump:

```
dwarfdump --uuid example.app/example
UUID: AA5E633E-FDA8-346C-AB92-B01320043DC3 (armv7) example.app/example
```

Afterwards you should check if the debug symbols you have also belong to that binary:

```
dwarfdump --uuid example.app.dSYM
UUID: AA5E633E-FDA8-346C-AB92-B01320043DC3 (armv7) example.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/example
```

In this example all assets fit together and you should be able to symbolicate your stacktrace.

Proceeding to the `symbolicatecrash` script:

In Xcode 8.3 you should be able to invoke the script via

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v example.crash 2> symbolicate.log
```

If it is not there you may run a `find . -name symbolicatecrash` in your Xcode.app directory to find it.

As you can see there are no more parameters given. So the script has to find your application binary and debug symbols by running a spotlight search. It searches the debug symbols with a specific index called `com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids`. You can do this search yourself:

```
mdfind 'com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids = *'
```

resp.

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == AA5E633E-FDA8-346C-AB92-B01320043DC3"
```

The first spotlight invocation gives you all indexed dSYM packages and the second one gives you the `.dSYM` packages with a specific UUID. If spotlight does not find your `.dSYM` package then `symbolicatecrash` will neither. If you do all this stuff e.g. in a subfolder of your `~/Desktop` spotlight should be able to find everything.

If `symbolicatecrash` finds your `.dSYM` package there should be a line like the following in `symbolicate.log`:

```
@dsym_paths = ( <SOME_PATH>/example.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/example )
```

For finding your `.app` package a spotlight search like the following is invoked by `symbolicatecrash`:

```
mdfind "kMDItemContentType == com.apple.application-bundle && (kMDItemAlternateNames == 'example.app' || kMDItemDisplayName == 'example' || kMDItemDisplayName == 'example.app')"
```

If `symbolicatecrash` finds your `.app` package there should be the following extract in `symbolicate.log`:

```
Number of symbols in <SOME_PATH>/example.app/example: 2209 + 19675 = 21884
Found executable <SOME_PATH>/example.app/example
-- MATCH
```

If all those resources are found by `symbolicatecrash` it should print out the symbolicated version of your crash log.

If not you can pass in your dSYM and .app files directly.

```
symbolicatecrash -v --dsym <SOME_PATH>/<App_URI>.app.dSYM/<APP_NAME>.app.dsym <CRASHFILE> <SOME_OTHER_PATH>/<APP_NAME>.app/<APP_NAME> > symbolicate.log
```

**Note:** The symbolicated backtrace will be output to terminal, not `symbolicate.log`.

Comment: i can find all the files however i get this, and no symbolicated output `No crash report version in testlog.crash at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash line 921.`

Comment: This was really helpful! In my case the .app file has different name than the executable name (I do not know why but it is built this way by Xcode). After renaming .app file in the XCode archive, the symbolicating did work.

Comment: This is a great explanation and should be the top answer IMO, thank you. Note that you may have to set your `DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable if the script complains about it like so: ``export DEVELOPER_DIR=`xcode-select --print-path` ``. I added this line to my `~/.bash_profile`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11682789/350761

Comment: There is an app in appstore that I found, that helps to find and symbolicate crash logs.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/symbolicator/id705354958?ls=1&mt=12

Comment: Note that for Xcode 5, this has moved to:
<PATH_TO_Xcode.app>/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/symbolicatecrash

Comment: symbolicate crash also has several helpful options.
`<SYMBOL_PATH>               Additional search paths in which to search for symbol rich binaries`

`-o | --output <OUTPUT_FILE> The symbolicated log will be written to OUTPUT_FILE. Defaults to "-" (i.e. stdout) if not specified`

`-d | --dsym <DSYM_BUNDLE>   Adds additional dSYM that will be consulted if and when a binary's UUID matches (may be specified more than once)`

Comment: I can't, for the life of me, seem to get this to work...my .app and .dSYM file are in the same directory, from which I'm running 'symbolicatecrash', but the output (both to terminal and log file) is simply blank. Anyone encountered this? I also tried specifying the app and .dsym manually, same result.

Comment: Regarding his step "You can check the UUID of the binary package you have with dwarfdump:"   If your app has a space in name then your dwarfdump would look like this:  "$ dwarfdump --uuid 'Your Appname.app'/Your_Appname"    In the second part it replaces the space with an underscore.

Answer (score 115):

With the latest version of Xcode (3.2.2), you can drag and drop any crash reports into the Device Logs section of the Xcode Organiser and they will automatically by symbolicated for you.  I think this works best if you built that version of the App using Build & Archive (also part of Xcode 3.2.2)

Comment: This is simply not working with Xcode4, on a fresh install. Seems to be a new bug :(

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves the same problem you have, but someone has  patched the symbolicate script https://github.com/nskboy/symbolicatecrash-fix YMMV :)

Comment: I had some *partial* success with that script; it failed on approx 50% of the Apple library calls though, reported lots of errors along the lines of "armv7 architecture not found". With Xcode 3.x, I'd get symbolication on 99% of calls.

Comment: This tip works with Xcode 4.2. Place crashlogs in Device Logs of Organizer. Restart the Organizer will get symbolicated crash logs !!! Thanks.

Comment: This didn't work from me when I imported an archive file from another computer to get a crash log.  :(  For this reason I had to manually symbolicate the file.  You can find steps on how to do the symbolication here: [iPhone SDK : Where is symbolicatecrash.sh located?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8648232/590956)

Comment: Make sure the first line in your crash report is... `Incident Identifier: 12345` (where 12345 is a random string of numbers) otherwise XCode wont let you import it.  I was using CrashReporter.framework and it was generating the first line as `Incident Identifier: [TODO]` and that was causing XCode to reject it

Comment: Don't work for me with downloaded crash reports from iTunes Connect.

Comment: Works great with XCode 5.1 This is much simpler than using the terminal.

Comment: For people that have the same problem as @Altaveron - Symbolicating a crash log requires the system files from a similar device running the same system version as the crash log. Check the iOS version (e.g. 7.1.2 (11D257)) from which the crash log comes, and plug in a device in Xcode that has that same version, so Xcode can extract the symbols. You can check if you have the correct symbols in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/

Comment: This doesn't work with iTunes Connect which is asked in the question.

Answer (score 75):

I did this successfully, using the following steps.

**Step 1:** Create a folder in desktop, I give name it to "CrashReport" and put three files ("MYApp.app", "MyApp.app.dSYM", "MYApp_2013-07-18.crash") in it.

**Step 2:** Open Finder and go to Applications, where you will find the Xcode application, right click on this and Click "Show Package Contents", after this follow this simple path.
 "Contents->Developer->Platforms->iPhoneOS.platform->Developer->Library->PrivateFrameworks->**DTDeviceKit.framework**->Versions->A->Resources"

OR

"Contents->Developer->Platforms->iPhoneOS.platform->Developer->Library->PrivateFrameworks->**DTDeviceKitBase.framework**->Versions->A->Resources"

OR

For Xcode 6 and above the path is
Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources

Where you find "symbolicatecrash" file, copy this and paste it to "CrashReport" folder.

**Step 3:** launch the terminal, run these 3 Command

1. cd  /Users/mac38/Desktop/CrashReport and  press Enter button
2. export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" and press Enter
3. ./symbolicatecrash -A -v MYApp_2013-07-18.crash MyApp.app.dSYM and press Enter Now its Done..  (NOTE: versions around 6.4 or later do not have the -A option -- just leave it out).

Comment: for DTServiceKit look in Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks

Comment: Thank Thank you... as of April 9, 2015, this is what worked for me flawlessly. One thing, is that I got `Unknown option: A` for symbolicatecrash, but the process ran anyway

Comment: I wish I could give a thousand points to this answer. There are so many how-to's on this topic... but this is the one that works at the lowest level so it ALWAYS works. It's a pain in the rear to hit all the steps, but when everything else fails, this does the job.

Answer (score 37):

### Steps to symbolicate a crash report automatically using XCode:

**UPDATED FOR XCODE 9**

1. Connect ***any*** iOS device to your Mac (yes a physical one, yes I know this is stupid)
2. Choose "Devices" from the "Window" menu
   [image]
3. Click your device on the left and VIEW DEVICE LOGS on the right
   [image]
4. Wait. It might take a minute to show up. Maybe doing `Command-A` then `Delete` will speed this up.
5. ***Critical undocumented step:*** rename the crash report that you got from iTunesConnect from `.txt` extension to `.crash` extension
6. Drag the crash report into that area on the left
   [image]

And then Xcode will symbolicate the crash report and display the results.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: This is the official Apple procedure. Should be the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm adding pictures now. Also included the SUPER UNDOCUMENTED step. I thought about make a git of red text and splicing it in there so that it would really stand out. Then I stopped thinking about that.

Comment: Thank you! None of the other answers actually say that the device you use does not need to be the device (or even device type) that the crash occurred on.

Comment: Quick note, because for me it would not re-symbolicate.  I had to also open Organizer, click the build in Archives, click Download Debug Symbols. Then I could re-symbolicate in the device log view.  This was for a crash log downloaded from Apple after a rejected review.

Answer (score 28):

I also put dsym, app bundle, and crash log together in the same directory before running symbolicate crash

Then I use this function defined in my .profile to simplify running symbolicatecrash:

```
function desym
{
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -A -v $1 | more
}
```

The arguments added there may help you.

You can check to make sure spotlight "sees" your dysm files by running the command:

```
mdfind 'com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids = *'
```

Look for the dsym you have in your directory.

NOTE: As of the latest Xcode, there is no longer a Developer directory. You can find this utility here:

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Vers‌​ions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash**

Comment: I looked at the mdfind output, and the dSYM file can definitely be seen by spotlight.
However, the symbolicatecrash script still doesn't output anything different from the crash report itself. Even using the arguments you provided.

Comment: The script should produce some warning text at the beginning if it cannot find the dsym - can you look for that and see what it says?

Comment: Also, try adding "." after the command, so it would be "symbolicatecrash -A -v MyApp.crashlog ." .  That forces it to look in the current directory if it's not doing so already.

Comment: Meaning "Can't exec "/usr/bin/xcode-select": No such file or directory at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/Resources/symbolicatecrash line 49."

Comment: Oops, apparently there is another SO question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859852/error-while-executing-symbolicatecrash-command-cant-exec-usr-bin-xcode-select

Comment: This did not directly work. But this did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675863/atos-cannot-get-symbols-from-dsym-of-archived-application

Comment: Since Xcode 6, symbolicatecrash is located here : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash

Answer (score 28):

I use Airbrake in my apps, which does a fairly good job of remote error logging.

Here's how I symbolicate them with atos if the backtrace needs it:

1. In Xcode (4.2) go to the organizer, right click on the archive from
   which the .ipa file was generated.
2. In Terminal, cd ***into the xcarchive*** for instance `MyCoolApp 10-27-11 1.30 PM.xcarchive`
3. Enter the following `atos -arch armv7 -o 'MyCoolApp.app'/'MyCoolApp'`
   (don't forget the single quotes)
4. I don't include my symbol in that call. What you get is a block cursor on an empty line.
5. Then I copy/paste my symbol code at that block cursor and press
   enter.  You'll see something like:

   `-[MyCoolVC dealloc] (in MyCoolApp) (MyCoolVC.m:34)`
6. You're back to a block cursor and you can paste in other symbols.

Being able to go through your backtrace one item without re-entering the first bit is a nice time saver.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 21):

Just a simple and updated answer for xcode 6.1.1 .

STEPS

1.Xcode>Window>Devices.

2.Select a device from a list of devices under DEVICES section.

3.Select View Device Logs.

4.Under the All Logs section you can directly drag drop the report.crash

5.Xcode will automatically Symbolicate the crash report for you.

6.You can find the Symbolicated crash report by matching its Date/Time with the Date/Time mentioned in your crash report.

Comment: Crash reports which I have downloaded from Apple Resolution Center usually have extension of .txt. Remember to rename them to .crash, otherwise Device Logs may refuse to add them. Work well for my current XCode 6.3.1

Comment: This is the official Apple procedure. Should be the answer.
Apple link: [Technical Note TN2151:
Understanding and Analyzing iOS Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: How do we do this if the crash came from Apple/ iTunesConnect? So in other words we don't actually know or have the device that the crash occurred on?

Answer (score 14):

Even though I had been developing apps for a few years now, this was my first time debugging a binary and I felt like a complete NOOB figuring out where all the files were i.e. where is *.app *.dSYM and crash logs?  I had to read multiple posts in order to figure it out. Picture is worth a thousand words and I hope this post helps anyone else in future.

1- First go to itunesconnect and download your crash logs. 
NOTE: Is most cases you may get something like "Too few reports have been submitted for a report to be shown." Basically not enough users have submitted crash log reports to Apple in which case you can't do much of anything at that point.

[image]

[image]

2- Now if you had not changed your code since you had submitted your binary it to Apple then Launch Xcode for that project and do Product --> Archive again. Otherwise just find your latest submitted binary and right click on it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Using Xcode 4, the task is even simpler:

- open *Organizer*,
- click on *Library | Device Log* in the left column
- click on "*Import*" button on the bottom of the screen...

and voilà. The log file is imported and Symbolized automatically for you.  Provided you Archived the build using *Xcode -> Product -> Archive* first.

Comment: Strange enough, importing has no effect. Putting .app, .dSYM and .crash and then running symbolicatecrash on .crash file (without any additional arguments) worked though (XCode 4)

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 4.2.1, open *Organizer*, then go to *Library/Device Logs* and drag your .crash file into the list of crash logs. It will be symbolicated for you after a few seconds.

Note that you must use the same instance of Xcode that the original build was archived on (i.e. the archive for your build must exist in *Organizer*).

Answer (score 7):

The magical Xcode Organizer isn't that magical about symbolicating my app. I got no symbols at all for the crash reports that I got back from Apple from a failed app submission.

I tried using the command-line, putting the crash report in the same folder as the .app file (that I submitted to the store) and the .dSYM file:

```
$ symbolicatecrash "My App_date_blahblah-iPhone.crash" "My App.app"
```

This only provided symbols for my app and not the core foundation code, but it was better than the number dump that Organizer is giving me and was enough for me to find and fix the crash that my app had. If anyone knows how to extend this to get Foundation symbols it would be appreciated.

Comment: For core Foundation dSYM, a (may be chinese) guy out there had uploaded the dSYM on his shared google drive, just download it and throw in to "devices supported" folder and it will be solved. https://github.com/Zuikyo/iOS-System-Symbols

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was dragging crash reports directly from Mail to the Organizer. For some reason, that prevented the crash reports from getting symbolicated (I'd love to know why).

Copying the crash reports to the Desktop first, and then dragging them from there to the Organizer got them symbolicated properly.

Very specific case, I know. But thought I'd share just in case.

Comment: I imagine this may have something to do with spotlight. Is there any chance the location where the organizer keeps your logs wasn't being indexed by spotlight?

Answer (score 4):

Here's another issue I have with symbolicatecrash – it won't work with Apps that have spaces in their bundle (i.e. 'Test App.app'). Note I don't think you can have spaces in their name when submitting so you should remove these anyway, but if you already have crashes that need analysing, patch symbolicatecrash (4.3 GM) as such:

```
240c240
<         my $cmd = "mdfind \"kMDItemContentType == com.apple.application-bundle && kMDItemFSName == $exec_name.app\"";
---
>         my $cmd = "mdfind \"kMDItemContentType == com.apple.application-bundle && kMDItemFSName == '$exec_name.app'\"";
251c251
<             my $cmd = "find \"$archive_path/Products\" -name $exec_name.app";
---
>             my $cmd = "find \"$archive_path/Products\" -name \"$exec_name.app\"";
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I filled a rdar on this and it's fixed in [redacted]

Answer (score 4):

For those using Airbrake, there's a solid response above but it wouldn't work for me without tweaking:

Works for some memory addresses but not others, not sure why...

- Create new dir on desktop or wherever
- Find archive in question in Xcode organizer
- Double tap to reveal in finder
- Double tap to show bundle contents
- Copy .dSYM file and .app file into new dir
- cd into new dir
- Run this command: atos -arch armv7 -o 'Vimeo.app'/'Vimeo'
- Terminal will enter an interactive move
- Paste in memory address and hit enter, it will output method name and line number
- Alternatively, enter this command: atos -arch armv7 -o 'Vimeo.app'/'Vimeo' 
  To get info for one address only

Answer (score 4):

The combination that worked for me was:

1. Copy the dSYM file into the directory where the crash report was
2. Unzip the ipa file containing the app ('unzip MyApp.ipa')
3. Copy the application binary from the resulting exploded payload into the same folder as the crash report and symbol file (Something like "MyApp.app/MyApp")
4. Import or Re-symbolicate the crash report from within Xcode's organizer

Using **atos** I wasn't able to resolve the correct symbol information with the addresses and offsets that were in the crash report. When I did this, I see something more meaningful, and it seems to be a legitimate stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do a lot of hacking of the symbolicatecrash script to get it to run properly.

As far as I can tell, symbolicatecrash right now requires the .app to be in the same directory as the .dsym.  It will use the .dsym to locate the .app, but it won't use the dsym to find the symbols.

You should make a copy of your symbolicatecrash before attempting these patches which will make it look in the dsym:

Around line 212 in the getSymbolPathFor_dsymUuid function

```
212     my @executablePath = grep { -e && ! -d } glob("$dsymdir" . "/Contents/Resources/DWARF/" . $executable);
```

Around line 265 in the matchesUUID function

```
265             return 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple, after searching a lot i found clear steps to symbolicate whole crash log file.

- copy .app , crash_report and DSYM files in a folder.
- connect the device with xcode
- Then go to window -> select devices -> view device logs
- Then select this device, delete all logs .
- drag and drop your crash on device log section . it will automatically symbolicate the crash . just right click on report and export it .

happy coding,
Riyaz

Comment: best  short and sweet ans, follow each and every step written in this ans .       https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html follow this link to find the difference between unsymbolicated and fully symbolicated.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a **script** that will symbolicate all my crash logs.

### Preconditions

Create a folder and put there 4 things:

1. `symbolicatecrash` perl script - there are many SO answers that tells it's location
2. The archive of the build that match the crashes (from Xcode Organizer. simple as `Show in Finder` and copy) [I don't sure this is necessery]
3. All the `xccrashpoint` packages - (from Xcode Organizer. `Show in Finder`, you may copy all the packages in the directory, or the single xccrashpoint you would like to symbolicate)
4. Add that short script to the directory:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   echo "cleaning old crashes from directory"
   rm -P *.crash
   rm -P *.xccrashpoint
   rm -r allCrashes
   echo "removed!"
   echo ""
   echo "--- START ---"
   echo ""

   mkdir allCrashes
   mkdir symboledCrashes
   find `ls -d *.xccrashpoint` -name "*.crash" -print -exec cp {} allCrashes/ \;

   cd allCrashes
   for crash in *.crash; do
       ../symbolicatecrash $crash > ../symboledCrashes/V$crash
   done
   cd ..

   echo ""
   echo "--- DONE ---"
   echo ""
   ```

### The Script

When you run the script, you'll get 2 directories.

1. `allCrashes` - all the crashes from all the `xccrashpoint` will be there.
2. `symboledCrashes` - the same crashes but now with all the symbols.
3. you DON'T need to clean the directory from old crashes before running the script. it will clean automatically. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found out most of proposed alternatives did not work in latest XCode (tested with Xcode 10). For example, I had no luck drag-dropping .crash logs in Xcode -> Organizer -> Device logs -view.

I recommend using Symbolicator tool https://github.com/agentsim/Symbolicator

- Git clone Symbolicator repository and compile and run with Xcode
- Copy .crash file (ascii file, with stack trace in begging of file) and .xarchive of crashing release to same temporarly folder
- Drag and drop .crash file to Symbolicator icon in Dock
- In 5-30 secs symbolicated crash file is produced in same folder as .crash and .xarchive are

Answer (score 0):

In order to symbolicate crashes, Spotlight must be able to find the .dSYM file that was generated at the same time the binary you submitted to Apple was. Since it contains the symbol information, you will be out of luck if it isn't available.

Comment: If you read the question, I stated that I have saved the original dSYM file that was generated at the same time the binary was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I got a bit grumpy about the fact nothing here seems to "just work" so I did some investigating and the result is:

Set up: QuincyKit back end that receives reports. No symbolication set up as I couldn't even begin to figure out what they were suggesting I do to make it work.

The fix: download crash reports from the server online. They're called 'crash' and by default go into the ~/Downloads/ folder. With that in mind, this script will "do the right thing" and the crash reports will go into Xcode (Organizer, device logs) and symbolication will be done.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copy crash reports so that they appear in device logs in Organizer in Xcode

if [ ! -e ~/Downloads/crash ]; then 
   echo "Download a crash report and save it as $HOME/Downloads/crash before running this script."
   exit 1
fi

cd ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/
mkdir -p actx # add crash report to xcode abbreviated
cd actx

datestr=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S"`

mv ~/Downloads/crash "actx-app_"$datestr"_actx.crash"
```

Things can be automated to where you can drag and drop in Xcode Organizer by doing two things if you do use QuincyKit/PLCR.

Firstly, you have to edit the remote script admin/actionapi.php ~line 202. It doesn't seem to get the timestamp right, so the file ends up with the name 'crash' which Xcode doesn't recognize (it wants something dot crash):

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="crash'.$timestamp.'.crash"');
```

Secondly, in the iOS side in QuincyKit BWCrashReportTextFormatter.m ~line 176, change `@"[TODO]"` to `@"TODO"` to get around the bad characters.

Answer (score 0):

atos is being deprecated so if you are running OSX 10.9 or later you may need to run

`xcrun atos`

> Warning: /usr/bin/atos is moving and will be removed from a future OS
>   X release. It is now available in the Xcode developer tools to be
>   invoked via: `xcrun atos`

Comment: Seems Apple is allowing for the DWARF format to morph with each release of the tools (makes sense, especially with the advent of Swift) so they're moving it to the tool distro.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Textwrangler to pinpoint errors in an original app upload binary rejection. (The crash data will be found in your itunesConnect account.)  Using Sachin's method above I copy the original.crash to TextWrangler, then copy the symbolicatecrash file I've created to another TextWrangler file. Comparing the two files pinpoints differences. The symbolicatecrash file will have differences which point out the file and line number of problems.

Answer (score 0):

## For those looking for a working solution in 2022

Steps to **Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports**

- Convert apple provided crash log in `.txt` format to `.crash`
- `Xcode > Window > Devices and simulators`
- **Must select a connected & running ios device.** (not a simulator, or offline device)
- Select `All Logs` section, drag & drop the `.crash` file

---

Note that, the other solutions having `symbolicatecrash` is deprecated and its usage shows:

> ⚠️  symbolicatecrash is deprecated; it will be removed in future releases of Xcode ⚠️

Answer (score -2):

We use Google Crashlytics to supervise crash logs, the feeling is very timely and convenient to use.

Document links：
https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#missing-dsyms

All about Missing dSYMs
Fabric includes a tool to automatically upload your project’s dSYM. The tool is executed through the /run script, which is added to your Run Script Build Phase during the onboarding process. There can be certain situations however, when dSYM uploads fail because of unique project configurations or if you’re using Bitcode in your app. When an upload fails, Crashlytics isn’t able to symbolicate and display crashes, and a “Missing dSYM” alert will appear on your Fabric dashboard.

Missing dSYMs can be manually uploaded following the steps outlined below.

Note:
As an alternative to the automated dSYM upload tool, Fabric provides a command-line tool (upload-symbols)) that can be manually configured to run as part of your project’s build process. See the upload-symbols section below for configuration instructions.

...